# How to save more values in XML

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have a textfield where user can fill in strings under each other. But how to save now the different strings. Because now it is one long string. And not seperated strings
This is the class for Serialize and Deserialize:

```
public class PreConditionSettings
    {
        [Display(Name = "PreConditionResidentsOnly", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public bool ResidentsOnly { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "PreConditionMinimumAge", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public int MinimumAge { get; set; }

        [SfsHelpers.PreConditionRedirectValidation(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product), ErrorMessageResourceName="PreConditionRedirectUrlValidation")]
        [Display(Name = "PreConditionRedirectUrl", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "PreConditionIpAddress", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }

        public PreConditionSettings() {
            this.ResidentsOnly = false;
            this.MinimumAge = 0;
            this.RedirectUrl = null;
            this.IpAddress = null;
        }

        internal string Serialize(EditProductModel model) {
            if (this.ResidentsOnly == false && this.MinimumAge == 0)
                return model.Product.AuthenticationSettings;

            XElement settings = XElement.Parse(model.Product.AuthenticationSettings ?? "<settings/>");
            if (settings == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired") == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired").Value != "true")
                return model.Product.AuthenticationSettings;

            settings.Add(
                new XElement("preconditions",
                    new XElement("residentsonly", this.ResidentsOnly ? "1" : "0"),
                    new XElement("minimumage", this.MinimumAge),
                    new XElement("redirecturl", this.RedirectUrl),
                    new XElement("ipaddress", this.IpAddress)
                )
            );

            return settings.ToString();
        }

        internal void Deserialize(EditProductModel model) {
            Deserialize(model.Product);
        }

        internal void Deserialize(Product product) {
            XElement settings = XElement.Parse(product.AuthenticationSettings ?? "<settings/>");

            if (settings == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired") == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired").Value != "true")
                return;

            XElement conditions = settings.Element("preconditions");
            if (conditions == null)
                return;

            XElement condition = conditions.Element("residentsonly");
            if (condition!= null)
                this.ResidentsOnly = (condition.Value == "1");

            condition = conditions.Element("minimumage");
            if (condition != null) {
                int age = 0;
                if (Int32.TryParse(condition.Value, out age))
                    this.MinimumAge = age;
            }

            condition = conditions.Element("redirecturl");
            if (condition != null) {
                this.RedirectUrl = condition.Value;
            }

            condition = conditions.Element("ipaddress");
            if (condition != null) {
                this.IpAddress = condition.Value;
            }
        }
```

And it is about the propertie: IpAddress. The output of this is:

```
<settings authenticationrequired="true">
  <accesslevel>level10</accesslevel>
  <profile>test</profile>
  <preconditions>
    <residentsonly>1</residentsonly>
    <minimumage>55</minimumage>
    <redirecturl>/page/newpage</redirecturl>
    <ipaddress>88888888
999999999</ipaddress>
  </preconditions>
</settings>
```

But you see that it is one string, and not two strings: 88888888 and 999999999.

Thank you

I try it like this:

```
condition = conditions.Element("ipaddress");
        if (condition != null) {
            string[] lines = IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            this.IpAddress = condition.Value;
        }
```

I try it something like this:

```
condition = conditions.Element("ipaddress");
            if (condition != null) {
                string[] lines = IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
               string lines = string.Join("\n",condition.Value);
                //this.IpAddress = condition.Value;
            }
```

If I try this:

```
condition = conditions.Element("ipaddress");
            if (condition != null) {

                string[] lines = IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
                    lines[i] = condition.Value.ToString();
                    //lines = string.Join("\n", condition.Value.ToArray());
                }

                //lines = string.Join("\n",condition.Value);
                //this.IpAddress = condition.Value;
            }
```

I get this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

on this line:

```
 string[] lines = IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split your string IpAddress by \n or Environment.NewLine and save as array of strings.

After your edits :

```
condition = conditions.Element("ipaddress");
if (condition != null) {
    string[] lines = condition.Value.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    this.IpAddress = new XElement("ipaddresses", lines.Select(o=> new XElement("item", o))).ToString();
}
```

Comment: But what comes after: StringSplitOptions.. because it is not finished that line. You mean .NONe?

Comment: @SavantTheIncredible yes, was deleted by mistake. I edited answer.

Comment: Hi Backs, I just put a other question. What is almost the same. But this question makes it more clear. Can you look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785290/splitting-string-and-save-to-xml Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to either change the property to an ICollection or create a custom type IpAddresses, implementing ICollection and custom serialization/business logic.

This would bring the following change to your xml file:

```
<ipaddresses>
    <item>88888888</item>
    <item>99999999</item>
</ipaddresses>
```