# splitting string and save to xml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a textfield you can enter strings(numbers), like this: 
78787.8888 
8777.99999

and the values has to be saved like this:

```
<ipaddresses>
<ipaddress>78787.8888  </ipaddress>
<ipaddress>8777.99999  </ipaddress>
</ipaddresses>
```

I am using for this a serialize method, like this:

```
internal string Serialize(EditProductModel model) {
            if (this.ResidentsOnly == false && this.MinimumAge == 0)
                return model.Product.AuthenticationSettings;

            XElement settings = XElement.Parse(model.Product.AuthenticationSettings ?? "<settings/>");
            if (settings == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired") == null || settings.Attribute("authenticationrequired").Value != "true")
                return model.Product.AuthenticationSettings;

            settings.Add(    
                new XElement("preconditions",
                    new XElement("residentsonly", this.ResidentsOnly ? "1" : "0"),
                    new XElement("minimumage", this.MinimumAge),
                    new XElement("redirecturl", this.RedirectUrl),
                    new XElement("ipaddress", this.IpAddress)
                )
            );


            XElement ipaddresses = new XElement("ipaddresses");
            string[] lines = ipaddresses.Value.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            foreach (var item in lines) {
                lines.Select(ip=> new XElement("item", ip)).ToString();

            }




            settings.Add(ipaddresses);


            return settings.ToString();
        }
```

But everytime lines is "".

and this is the propertie:

```
 [Display(Name = "PreConditionIpAddress", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public string[] IpAddress { get; set; }
```

Thank you.

Oke, I have it now like this:

```
 XElement ipaddresses = new XElement("ipaddresses");
            string[] lines = IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var item in lines) {   

               // lines.Select(ip => new XElement("ipaddress", ip)).ToString();
                settings.Add(new XElement("ipaddress", item));

            }
```

and I get:

```
<ipaddress>78787.8888  </ipaddress>
<ipaddress>8777.99999  </ipaddress>
```

but how to get it like this:

```
<ipaddresses>
<ipaddress>78787.8888  </ipaddress>
<ipaddress>8777.99999  </ipaddress>
</ipaddresses>
```

Thank you

Comment: Step trough it in a debugger, itll quickly show you where the problem is

Comment: where are the `ipaddresses` values stored? You need to pass the to the `XElement` constructor

Comment: Hi Ned. I changed the post. I added the propertie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created *ipaddresses* node but you're adding the *ipaddress* notes directly under settings. So if you add the nodes to *ipaddresses* first then add that node to parent it should work. Something like this:

```
XElement ipaddresses = new XElement("ipaddresses");
string[] lines = IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var item in lines) 
{  
    ipaddresses.Add(new XElement("ipaddress", item));
}

settings.Add(ipaddresses);
```